# Define Interface for observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a function in an angular component.ts file like

```
createOrUpdateAlertingProfile() {

**let request: Observable<any>;**
let successMessage: string;

if (!this.alertingProfile) {
  const slackConfigurationIdvalue = this.createOrEditAlertingProfileForm.get('slackConfigurationId').value;
  const organizationIdvalue = this.createOrEditAlertingProfileForm.get('organizationId').value;
  const remiderValue = this.createOrEditAlertingProfileForm.get('reminder').value;
  const newAlertingProfileValue: AlertingProfileCreation = {
    ...this.createOrEditAlertingProfileForm.value,
    slackConfigurationId: slackConfigurationIdvalue === '' ? undefined : slackConfigurationIdvalue,
    organizationId: organizationIdvalue === '' ? undefined : organizationIdvalue,
    reminder: remiderValue === '' ? undefined : remiderValue,
    emails: this.emails.length === 0 ? undefined : this.emails.value,
    webhooks: this.webhooks.length === 0 ? undefined : this.webhooks.value,
  };
  request = this.alertingProfilesService.createAlertingProfile(newAlertingProfileValue);
  successMessage = 'New alerting profile was successfully added';
}

if (this.alertingProfile) {
  request = this.alertingProfilesService.updateAlertingProfile(this.createOrEditAlertingProfileForm.value);
  successMessage = `Alerting profile ${this.alertingProfile.name} was updated`;
}

request.subscribe(
  () => {
    this.alertify.success(successMessage);
    this.isLoading$.next(false);
    this.dialogRef.close(true);
  },
  (error) => {
    this.alertify.error('\n' + error);
    this.isLoading$.next(false);
  },
 );
}
```

the 'request' is of type observable

the request calls either of two services

```
createAlertingProfile(newAlertingProfile: AlertingProfileCreation) {
 return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/create`, newAlertingProfile);
}

updateAlertingProfile(model: AlertingProfileUpdate) {
 return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/edit`, model);
}
```

The two interfaces used 'AlertingProfileCreation' and 'AlertingProfileUpdate'

```
export interface AlertingProfileUpdate {
 name: string;
 slackConfigurationId: number;
 organizationId: number;
 reminder: number;}

export interface AlertingProfileCreation {
 name: string;
 slackConfigurationId: number;
 organizationId: number;
 emails: AlertingProfileEmail[];
 webhooks: Webhook[];
 reminder: number;}
```

My question is I want to define type for request observable and when I try

```
let request: Observable<AlertingProfileUpdate | AlertingProfileCreation>
```

It throws error, how can I define interface for Observable?

Comment: It will not work without typecasting anyway as at the point `request.subscribe(` it can be either one observable or the other. Therfore, your subscribe method would have either handle both `AlertingProfileUpdate | AlertingProfileCreation` or cast it to `any` to relax the compiler. Other than that, it could work if you would only use the cross section of both interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Observable<AlertingProfileUpdate> | Observable<AlertingProfileCreation>`
but keep in mind that you will be able to access only the crossesction of both interfaces (in typesafe manners speaking)

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgPICNoB4AqA%20A3sOcAHAVyXAEtQ5oTpQAnMpAUwApqkAuFgFw-QEoAvJgBuAezIATfh3FTc%20PHAC%20wVSCYAPAmLrc4ZAHbcmdAGaRQTOAEFwp7kYDmABTpizZewFUCkyCZwCoaQALZMHFTcDIZOANx40FCgANYAwmKGnk5EdAFkmQCSkpGGRKHMdAlwuk6QhmQAXvlFJXBlFabVdEyhRpKmpeWVcepaOnoGxqYWVrb2es5uHl5MaT0thkF4IeGR0NHO1UmW6ZnZuZvFQ51VeLX1TVdtHSN4vZBe0PuHsdUA7kwkAALMRiFLfKIxJwAbQAut1ev1Bu1hl11HgzERDKBHJk4E4mNxkNAWDISag7A4lu5PD4-AEmJg4AAfRAoSkLRyxZZ0tYbPGGHBKOA9bi5LYAWQCwIAdGZwGC6Cxpdw5XlDJIxKEyQAqABM-AApPrBIIAAxwAD87SY-3ZaCpix5tNWvn8JkwZLgpTtDs51JdK3s6yYmy9-GqygSIDgeFAmQOcFCAE8SYJCcSUGSY8m0yhZexaAxmCwRMIFPg4AnDNAxPZZYqnGXZbsmJGRdXE-WmI2xM2RLKHg1moLih2q13az2%20wPZT0%20prTBOqzW6w2my2TqkMlkyDk8mPpLnV92N-2Wx8vPwAPQ3owiSDkSTVU-T89zwEgsEQ2-3wyPs%20r74GuM6boOC7InQf4Pk%20UhRpGQA)

Also, keep in mind that you should cast your http calls as well.

```
createAlertingProfile(newAlertingProfile: AlertingProfileCreation):Observable<ReturnTypeOfCreation> {
 return this.http.post<ReturnTypeOfCreation>(`${this.baseUrl}/create`, newAlertingProfile);
}

updateAlertingProfile(model: AlertingProfileUpdate):Observable<ReturnTypeOfUpdate> {
 return this.http.post<ReturnTypeOfUpdate>(`${this.baseUrl}/edit`, model);
}
```